# How to detect if OIDC authorization request needs to open in browser

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

I am developing mobile application that works with server side using OAuth2. For authorization we use OpenID Connect with [authorization code flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1). Typical step in the authorization process on mobile devices in this flow is to open authorization url in system browser and then capture redirect url with authorization code.

In case when user is required to enter login and password in browser it is OK. But we have some clients authorized by IP and in this case system browser auto closes immediately after launch and returns successful authorization. Such useless browser launch is annoying and I'd like to prevent it.

The only idea I have right now is to make direct HTTP authorize request with `prompt=none` parameter as described in https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest to try authorize by IP. And in case of `login_required` or `interaction_required` errors repeat it in system browser without `prompt` parameter.

> *prompt=none*
>
> The Authorization Server MUST NOT display any authentication or
> consent user interface pages. An error is returned if an End-User is
> not already authenticated or the Client does not have pre-configured
> consent for the requested Claims or does not fulfill other conditions
> for processing the request. The error code will typically be
> login_required, interaction_required, or another code defined in
> Section 3.1.2.6. This can be used as a method to check for existing
> authentication and/or consent

Is there any other way to detect moment in authorization flow when user interaction with web page is really needed? So I can open browser only if it is needed. And without additional requests useless for most clients.

Comment: Why are you looking for another way? This seems to work fine for your use-case, not? I'm not aware of other options to check the authentication status of a user.

Comment: @MvdD Our service works for many people and it's better not to make additional requests and increase backend load. Also interception of error in `prompt=none` case is not an easy task because of custom URL scheme in `redirect_uri`

Comment: This seems backwards, if I were asked this at work where I perform Application Security i'd simply inform the developer that authorization is an application decision. i,e, the state of the user was initially established via the challenge response mechanism of OAuth2, you may then decide in the application itself what kind of 'trust' has been established. Trust can be defined using session time or ACL enclosed in a cookie, JWT, HMAC etc. and if later elevated privileges are needed for a protected action you may require an authorisation check and perform an OIDC call to the authz url to verify

Comment: @Stof In my case there is no any previous interaction with user to check if he has trust from server. And avoiding of such requests is the reason of my question.

Comment: You're also using OIDC for establishing authenticity of an identity claimed by an individual, literally authorising an anonymous user as being who they claim. The word authorisation literally includes a challenge response mechanism, without it the only thing you have is blind trust without verification. It sounds like you're looking for a solution and want to use OIDC, whether or not OIDC solves the problem. You're probably best rethinking how you achieve your security assurances, OIDC is guiding you there and you're trying to get OIDC to act in a way that has no security characteristics

Answer (score -2):

Since you use OpenID Connect, you might think of enabling some other mechanism to maintain authorized state between application, backend and identity server.

One such scenario could be usage of Access and Refresh tokens,

- First login, end user authentication is mandatory
- Your app receive tokens (ID token, access token and refresh token)
- Customer use the app and app use access token to communicate with the backend
- Customer use the application second time
- You know previous access token is expired so you obtain a new access token using refresh token

Of course refresh token can expire or identity serve can revoke the access token for some reason (ex- user changing password). But IMO this is the best solution provided by specification itself.

Comment: OIDC/OAuth2 uses access and refresh token mechanism. And login web page appears during receiving of tokens as described in the OIDC/OAuth2 flow

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov haven't you heard about token refresh request which is a backend call, which does not involve the front end ?